# Dropdown button - materializecss framework

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm trying to make a dropdown button, but it is not working correctly, beacuse the button is working on mobile, but on a desktop not. This is the code:

**init.js**

```
  (function($){
  $(function(){

    $('.button-collapse').sideNav();
    $('select').material_select();
    $('.dropdown-button').dropdown();

  }); // end of document ready
})(jQuery); // end of JQuery name space
```

**html code**

```
<ul id="dropdown2" class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="#">Ustawienia</a></li>
    <?php if($this->session->userdata('u_group') > 1) { ?>
    <li><a href="#">Panel administratora</a>
 </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>

<li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown2"><?php echo $this->session->userdata('u_nick'); ?><i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
```

Comment: Check your imports, jQuery must be imported before materialize.js

Comment: it's not it....

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `btn` class to a tag who has `dropdown-button` class. Then it'll work. **Here is [codepen](http://codepen.io/T-P/pen/WGVXza)**

**HTML**

```
<ul id="dropdown2" class="dropdown-content">
  <li><a href="#">Ustawienia</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Panel administratora</a></li>
</ul>

<li> <!-- Add btn class to a tag -->
  <a class="dropdown-button btn" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown2">Dropdown
    <i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i>
  </a>
</li>
```